# $E=\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4):\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2}\le x_1\right\}$, what is $\int_E e^{-\langle x,t\rangle} \, dx$?

Tags: integration

I'm learning some real analysis and encountered the following question:

Let $E=\left\{(x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4)\in \mathbb{R}^4:\sqrt{x_2^2+x_3^2+x_4^2}\le x_1\right\}$. for which values of $t\in\mathbb{R}^4$ is the integral the$\int_E e^{-\langle x,t\rangle} \, dx$ finite? Calculate the integral.

My first attempt was:

$$\int_Ee^{-\langle x,t\rangle}=\int_0^\infty e^{-x_1t_1}\left(\int_{B(0,x_1)}e^{-(x_2t_2+x_3t_3+x_4t_4)} \, dx_2 \, dx_3 \, dx_4\right) \, dx_1$$
But I couldn't calculate the inner integral. So I tried the other way around:

$$\int_Ee^{-\langle x,t\rangle}=\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}e^{-(x_2 t_2 + x_3 t_3 + x_4 t_4)} \left( \int_{\sqrt{x_2^2 + x_3^2+x_4^2}}^\infty e^{-t_1x_1} \, dx_1 \right) \, dx_2 \, dx_3 \, dx_4$$
This way at least I can see that a necessary condition for this integral to be finite is $t_1>0$, but now I'm stuck. When I try to actually calculate it, it becomes incredibly messy.

I'm pretty sure that some sort of change of variables is needed here, but anything I tried got way too messy to handle.

Any suggestions?

**Edit**: I think I've got it partially, when $t_2^2+t_3^2+t_4^2 = 1$. I want to calculate

$$\int_{B(0,x_1)}e^{-(x_2t_2+x_3t_3+x_4t_4)} dx_2dx_3dx_4$$

To make it more readable, I'll calculate

$$\int_{B(0,R)}e^{-\langle y,s \rangle}dy$$

where $y,s \in \mathbb{R}^3$, and $||s||=1$. It is known from linear algebra that there exists an orthogonal matrix $A$ such that $As=(1,0,0)$. I'll make the change of variables $y=A^{-1}z$. Obviously we still integrate over $B(0,R)$ and the Jacobian is 1:
$$\int_{B(0,R)}e^{-\langle y,s \rangle}dy = \int_{B(0,R)}e^{-\langle A^{-1}z,s \rangle}dz$$

We know that

$$\langle A^{-1}z,s \rangle = \langle z, As \rangle = \langle z, (1,0,0) \rangle = z_1 $$ so we get:

$$\int_{B(0,R)}e^{-\langle A^{-1}z,s \rangle}dz = \int_{B(0,R)}e^{-z_1}dz = \int_{-R}^Re^{-z_1}\cdot vol(B(0,\sqrt{R^2-z_1^2}))dz_1 = \int_{-R}^R e^{-z_1}\pi(R^2-z_1^2)dz_1 = \pi\left(R^2\int_{-R}^Re^{-z_1}dz_1 -\int_{-R}^Re^{-z_1}z_1^2dz_1\right)$$

Some easy calculations using integration by parts give us the result:

$$ 2\pi(e^R(R+1)+e^{-R}(R-1))$$

Now let's return to $\int_0^\infty e^{-x_1t_1}\left(\int_{B(0,x_1)}e^{-(x_2t_2+x_3t_3+x_4t_4)} \, dx_2 \, dx_3 \, dx_4\right) \, dx_1$. We already calculated the inner integral($R=x_1$) so this integral equals to:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x_1t_1}2\pi(e^{x_1}(x_1+1)+e^{-x_1}(x_1-1)) \, dx_1 = 
2\pi \left( \int_0^\infty e^{x_1(1-t_1)}(x_1+1) \, dx_1 +\int_0^\infty e^{x_1(-1-t_1)}(x_1-1) \, dx_1 \right)$$

We can see in this case that if we want the integral to converge, $t_1$ must be greater then $1$. Simple calculus gives the final result:

$${1 \over (1-t_1)^2} + {1\over t_1-1} + {1\over(1+t_1)^2} - {1 \over t_1+1}$$

So this is my solution to the case $t_2^2+t_3^2+t_4^2 = 1$.

I'm not sure how to do the general case. I think I can somehow use the solution I found, but I don't know how.

Comment: Correct usage is $\langle x,t\rangle$, not $<x,t>$.  I fixed that and some other things. $\qquad$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the case $t_{2}^{2}+t_{3}^{2}+t_{4}^{2}= 1$ and $t_{1}>1$ I used Maple and got that
$$
\int_{-R}^{R}e^{-z_{1}}\pi(R^2 -z_{1}^{2})\, dz_{1} = 2\pi(e^{R}(R-1)+e^{-R}(R+1)),
$$
where $-1$ and $+1$ have changed places compared with your result. As a consequence 
$$
\int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x_1t_1}\left(\int_{B(0,x_1)}e^{-(x_2t_2+x_3+t_3+x_4t_4)}\, dx_2dx_3dx_4\right)\, dx_1 = \dfrac{8\pi}{(t_1^2-1)^2}.
$$

In the case  $t_1 > \sqrt{t_2^2+t_3^2+t_4^2} > 0$ I suggest a change of variables: $y_k = cx_k$ and $s_k = \dfrac{t_k}{c}$ for $k = 1, 2, 3, 4$, where $c = \sqrt{t_2^2+t_3^2+t_4^2}$.  Then
$$
\int_{E}e^{-<x,t>}\,dx = \dfrac{1}{c^4}\int_{E}e^{-\langle y,s\rangle}\,dy = \dfrac{1}{c^4}\dfrac{8\pi}{(s_1^2-1)^2} = \dfrac{8\pi}{(t_1^2 -(t_2^2+t_3^2+t_4^2))^2}.
$$
Finally you have to take care of the case $t_{1}> 0 = t_{2}= t_{3}= t_{4}$. Then
$$
\int_{E}e^{-\langle x,t\rangle}\,dx = \int_{0}^{\infty}e^{-x_1t_1}\dfrac{4\pi x_1^3}{3}\, dx_1 = \dfrac{8\pi}{t_1^4}.
$$